# Peer to Peer Communication without Server in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, websocket, socket.io, p2p

Is there any way to communicate between two devices or application with Browser of other devices without having Server in the middle?

If I explain, actually I want to share data between iPhone application and Browser of Desktop, I tried HTTPServer, & played with WebSocket too, but in these case this server plays an important role in between. So If somehow I exchange data between two peers like IP Address, Port number, Then Is it possible to communicate between those two devices using **Wi-fi channel** without having Server in Middle?

**The Way, Right now I have implemented.**

[image]

**The way, I am looking for.**

[image]

Comment: have you read about iBeacons?

Comment: Ibeacon is just to Location monitoring, I am looking for Data communication in form of Text, Binary data etc.

Comment: you can send data aswell

Comment: how you are proposing to do this? sockets bluetooth etc? wcf?

Comment: No you can't. If you are thinking about CoreBluetooth Peripheral then Its Yes, but in case of iBeacon its not possible

Comment: using iBeacons concept in Peripheral devices

Comment: how would you know the IP Address of your iPhone in network

Comment: Then its not IBeacon dear. I beacon is actually a technology that is exploiting BLE to location aware application

Comment: I am already getting Address and Port. My Concern is not that.

Comment: Then why you are not using UDP or TCP GCD

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80548/discussion-between-mrug-and-syed-ali-salman).

Answer (score -1):

I recently came across http://www.freedomjs.org/ which is suppose to provide p2p functionality in the browser.